# Convert Markdown to Github flavored Markdown

Tags: markdown, pandoc

What is the easiest way to convert the first kind of Markdown into the second kind of Markdown?

```
Headline 1
==========

Some text

Subheadline 1
-------------

More text

Headline 2
==========

Even more text
```

into

```
# Headline 1 #

Some text

## Subheadline 1 ##

More text

# Headline 2 #

Even more text
```

Linux or Mac OS X tools are preferred.

Comment: Both are normal markdown, the '#' ones are not specific to github-flavored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about the `#`s at the ends of lines, you can do

```
pandoc -f markdown -t markdown --atx-headers
```

See [the pandoc documentation section](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#atx-style-headers) on this for more.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to a multi-line capable GREP? The following works inside TextPad (which, admittedly, is a Windows program):

Search for

```
^(.+)\n=+$
```

replace with

```
# \1 #
```

and similar lines for heading #2. Notation of hard return in the find expression and of Insert Numbered Group in the replacement may differ per software.